# Hive query from external hbase table directly do not get the same row count from hive table created from the external table

Tags: hive, hbase

I created a hive external table linking to a hbase table, eg:

```
create external table user_test_external
(
 id   string,
 name string,
 age  string,
 createtime string
) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,info:name,info:age,info:createtime") TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "test_hbase");
```

Then I query all users created on '2018-10-17' from external table user_test_external, eg:

```
select count(*) from user_test_external where createtime = '2018-10-17'
```

Assume, I got the `row count = A`.

Now, I create a hive table from the external table `user_test_external`,

```
CREATE TABLE user_test AS 
SELECT * 
FROM user_test_external 
WHERE createtime = '2018-10-17'
```

Then, I count table `user_test` using

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  AS row_cnt
FROM  user_test 
WHERE createtime = '2018-10-17'
```

I got `row_cnt = B`, while A != B, When I use `desc formatted table user_test`, it will show row count = A .I was really confused by this wired result. Really Appreciate If anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason！Because there are columns that have multi-lines， while hive‘s default row delimeter is \n, so when you create a hive table from a hive external table, data rows is larger